# Улучшения ввода/вывода для алгоритма

Tags: java, алгоритм, io

Решил порешать задачи которые готовит [Яндекс](https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/8458/enter/).
Наткнулся на первые трудности в виде задачи про дубликаты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моё решение следующее:

```
 private void solve() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        Integer lastElement = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int current = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

            if (lastElement == null) {
                lastElement = current;
                System.out.println(current);
            }

            if (!lastElement.equals(current)) {
                System.out.println(current);
                lastElement = current;
            }
        }
    }
```

И это решение не проходит проверку системы, валится из-за превышение лимита использования памяти. Проблема в вводе/выводе? Если нет, то как её ещё можно решить?

Comment: stringBuilder не пробовали?

Comment: а для чего вы Integer используете? Приведите к Int и сравнивайте через ==

Comment: Для считывания из System.in лучше используй Scanner. Там даже не придется парсить в int, так как там есть свой метод для считывания int'ового значения

Comment: @danilshik Да, действительно, тип то переполняется :)

Comment: @SlandShow при прохождении курса по алгоритмам и структурам данных, при выполнении некоторых задач при использовании Scaner я не проходил в лимиты, а при BufferedReader, InputStreamReader проходил. Так что я бы не считал что Scaner работает быстрее, по крайней мере без тестов

Comment: Покажите остальную часть исходников

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar зачем? В этом нету нужды.

Comment: @SlandShow напишите ваше решение для будущих посетителей сайта, которые будут искать ответ на такой же ответ

Comment: lastElement.equals(current) - вызывает автобоксинг, что приводит к потреблению памяти, вообще вам надо только дубликаты убрать, а в этом случае вам даже не нужно преобразование к int, достаточно сравнивать строки

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev сравнивать строки - плохая идея, а вот если убрать класс-обертку на примитив - результат будет тот же...

Comment: @SlandShow чем плоха?

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev ну вот сравнение строк само по себе как работает, если не брать в расчет то что они берутся из одного пула? Это будет линейное сравнение внутри основного цикла.

Comment: @SlandShow по моему вы путаете сравнение строк по значению со сравнением их ссылок

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev а где гарантия что если мы берем строку из ввода/вывода, у нас она будет в пуле? 

Даже если мы будет производить операцию `intern()` над строкой, сравнение чисел на много лучше производить с точки зрения оптимизации и здравого смысла.

Comment: @SlandShow я смотрю, вы так и не поняли, что я предлагал использовать сравнение строк по значению, то есть equals

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev а что не так со сравнением чисел?

Comment: @SlandShow все так